# fpdf2: 'PDF' object has no attribute 'buffer'

Tags: python, exception, cs50, attributeerror, fpdf

i've been trying to insert a `__init__` method with the user's name asked as an input. the name is then transferred to my inherited FPDF object where i initialize with a new attribute: `username`. the thing is everything seems to work well except that when i'm adding a page with `pdf.add_page()` i get an AttributeError that my PDF object has not the attribute 'buffer' although i haven't touched the attribute and that it has completely inherited from my package.

here's my code:

```
from fpdf import FPDF
from fpdf import enums

class PDFcert(FPDF):
    def __init__(self, username):
        self.username = username

    def header(self):
        self.set_font("helvetica", "B", 50)
        self.cell(50, align="C")
        self.cell(100, 30, txt="CS50 Shirtificate", align="C")
        with self.local_context(blend_mode="Overlay"):
            self.image("./shirtificate.png", enums.Align.C, y=50, w=pdf.epw)
        self.set_font("helvetica", "B", 20)
        self.set_text_color(255)
        self.text(65, 120, txt=f"{self.username} took CS50")

def main():
    username = input("Name: ")
    pdf = PDFcert(username=username)
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.output("new-tuto2.pdf")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And i got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspaces/107498909/shirtificate/shirtificate.py", line 25, in <module>
    main()
  File "/workspaces/107498909/shirtificate/shirtificate.py", line 21, in main
    pdf.add_page()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fpdf/fpdf.py", line 818, in add_page
    if self.buffer:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'PDFcert' object has no attribute 'buffer'
```

here's where the attribute is located in the package:

```
...
if self.buffer:
    raise FPDFException(
        "A page cannot be added on a closed document, after calling output()"
    )
family = self.font_family
...
```

Plus, here **`buffer`** is the most detailed definition.

I thought first that my `username`  attribute was defined wrongly, so i tried other type of implementation of the attribute but still no signs of success.

What i'm actually trying to do is to print a text with the user's name, on a t-shirt.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAmoR.png)

Comment: Don't you need to do something like ```FPDF.__init__(self)``` or the like.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define FPDF as the superclass to your subclass PDFcert. This way PDFcert derives (inherits) attributes and methods from FPDF without having to implement them again.

To do this, add `super().__init__()` to your `__init__()`. Properly modified it will look like this:

```
class PDFcert(FPDF):
    def __init__(self, username):
        super().__init__()
        self.username = username
```

Once you fix this, you will get another error on the `self.image()` call.
You set `w=pdf.epw`, but the value needs to be the attribute of a PDF class instance. I will let you figure that out. :-)

This approach seems overly complicated to me -- especially if you don't understand inheritance. You could easily set the attributes in the body of `main()`. Why are you creating a new class to define the certificate's properties?